WTelegramClient link email for 2FA authorization
tell me how I can link mail when installing 2FA authorization.
Now I'm getting an error PASSWORD_HASH_INVALID
public async Task SetTwoAutorize()
   {
       try
       {
           //   const string old_password = "password";     // current password if any (unused otherwise)
           const string new_password = "new_pass"; // or null to disable 2FA
           var accountPwd = await _Client.Account_GetPassword();
           //  var password = accountPwd.current_algo == null ? null : await Client.InputCheckPassword(accountPwd, old_password);
           var password = accountPwd.current_algo == null ? null : await Client.InputCheckPassword(accountPwd, new_password);

           accountPwd.current_algo = null; // makes InputCheckPassword generate a new password
           var new_password_hash = new_password == null ? null : await Client.InputCheckPassword(accountPwd, new_password);
           await _Client.Account_UpdatePasswordSettings(password, new Account_PasswordInputSettings
           {
               email = "my_email",
               flags = Account_PasswordInputSettings.Flags.has_email,
               new_password_hash = new_password_hash?.A,
               
               new_algo = accountPwd.new_algo,
           });
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           string code = "";
           await _Client.Account_ConfirmPasswordEmail(code);
       }
   }

I tried to follow this pattern https://corefork.telegram.org/method/account.updatePasswordSettings But it didn't work out.

When creating 2FA authorization with mail binding, I used this code,
the Account_Confirm Password Email method is needed to return from the mail confirmation code function
/// <summary>
///  Install 2FA authorization
/// </summary>
/// <param name="email"></param>
/// <param name="new_password">or null to disable 2FA</param>
/// <param name="Account_ConfirmPasswordEmail"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task SetTwoAutorize(string email, string new_password, Func<Task<string>> Account_ConfirmPasswordEmail)
{
    try
    {
        //   const string old_password = "password";     // current password if any (unused otherwise)
        var accountPwd = await _Client.Account_GetPassword();
        //  var password = accountPwd.current_algo == null ? null : await Client.InputCheckPassword(accountPwd, old_password);
        var _password = accountPwd.current_algo == null ? null : await Client.InputCheckPassword(accountPwd, new_password);

        accountPwd.current_algo = null; // makes InputCheckPassword generate a new password
        var new_password_hash = new_password == null ? null : await Client.InputCheckPassword(accountPwd, new_password);
        await _Client.Account_UpdatePasswordSettings(_password, new Account_PasswordInputSettings
        {
            email = email,
            flags = Account_PasswordInputSettings.Flags.has_new_algo | Account_PasswordInputSettings.Flags.has_email,
            new_password_hash = new_password_hash?.A,
            new_algo = accountPwd.new_algo
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var code = await Account_ConfirmPasswordEmail.Invoke(); //The code for confirming the mail
        await _Client.Account_ConfirmPasswordEmail(code);
    }
}

